# How to change js code to php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Currently I am learning Php. For an Ebay shop I try to get my page free of JS and to switch to pure CSS via PHP. 
For this I have so far a backend, into which I enter my links and texts. These are stored in my menu.js.

```
$remote_directory = UPLOAD_PATH;
$renaming_file = $remote_directory . '/js/menu.js';
$renaming_file_to = $remote_directory . '/js/menu.old';
$_remc = new Admin_Remote_Copy(ADMIN_UPLOAD_SERVER_HOST, ADMIN_UPLOAD_USER_NAME, ADMIN_UPLOAD_PASSWORD, ADMIN_UPLOAD_SSH_PORT);
$_remc->remote_copy($renaming_file, $renaming_file_to);


if ($_remc->remote_is_writeable($renaming_file)) {
    $menu_string = "document.getElementById('categories_menu').innerHTML='";
    for ($z = 0; $z < count($_POST['menu_lvl1_text']); $z++) {

        $menu_string .= '<li><a href="' . $_POST['menu_lvl1_link'][$z] . '">' . htmlentities($_POST['menu_lvl1_text'][$z], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</a>';

        if (isset($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text']) && !empty($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text'])) {
            $menu_string .= '<ul>';
            for ($zs = 0; $zs < count($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text']); $zs++) {
                $menu_string .= '<li><a href="' . $_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_link'][$zs] . '">' . htmlentities($_POST['menu' . $z . '_lvl2_text'][$zs], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</a>';
            }
            $menu_string .= '</ul>';
        }
        $menu_string .= '</li>';
    }
    $menu_string .= "';";

    $_remc->remote_content_copy($renaming_file, $menu_string);
    $local_renaming_file = ADMIN_LOCAL_PATH . '/js/menu.js';
    $_remc->local_content_copy($local_renaming_file, $menu_string);
} else {
    $file_error = true;
}
```

Now I had thought to pass these values ​​into an array and save it via JSON PrittyPrint. However, I have no idea at all how to build this array.

My idea is to build a navigation with fixed IDs and fill it with the JSON file.

In the latter I see no problems, but the array is not clear to me.

Let's assume that array would look something like this:

```
$m =array(
    "10100" => array('menu_lvl1_text' => 'menu_lvl1_link'),
    "10101" => array('menu_lvl2_text' => 'menu_lvl2_link'),
    "10102" => array('menu_lvl2_text' => 'menu_lvl2_link'),
    "10103" => array('menu_lvl2_text' => 'menu_lvl2_link')
);
```

Am I on the wrong path? 
And how does my array know that it is to assign value 1 to ID 10000?

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to open a folder first! You can use some php functions like [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) at first then get or create a new file there.